# How to check for hidden number precision in an Excel range?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm comparing two ranges like this:

```
Set cell1 = SampleFeature.Cells(row, column)
Set cell2 = TestFeature.Cells(row, column)
If cell1.value <> cell2.value Then
    DoSomething()
End If
```

I have two ranges that, in the immediate window, show these values:

```
?cell1.Value
0.45
?cell2.Value
0.45
?cell1.Value=cell2.Value
False
?cell1-cell2
-5.55111512312578E-17
```

So this is pretty clearly a floating point precision issue.  My question is, how can I change the `cell1.value <> cell2.value` comparison so that it uses the precision given when I output `cell1.value`, as opposed to the "true" floating point value?

EDIT: sorry, forgot to mention that this check is also used to compare strings.

Comment: For formulas, you have [Precision as displayed](https://support.office.com/en-IE/article/Set-rounding-precision-e5d707e3-07a8-4df2-810c-218c531eb06a). For VBA, you must follow the general rules, which is to never compare floats for equality.

Comment: @ScottCraner, I want to compare them at whatever level of precision they have when their value is output in the Immediate window.  In this case it's 2 places, but it could be any number of places.

Comment: You could try rounding to the desired level of precision; or do your comparison by checking that the absolute difference between the two values is small enough to assure your desired level of precision.

Comment: This may be too specific of an answer but for the above you could `int(Cell1.value*100) <> int(Cell2.value*100)` if there isn't a more graceful way.

Comment: @RLH, in many cases there will be more than 2 places of precision.

Comment: @sigil, How will you determine what the precision is supposed to be and is it variable?

Comment: @RLH, it's whatever the precision is when I output the result of `?someRange.Value` to the Immediate window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()

  Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range

    Set Rng1 = Range("A1") ' just for test example
    Set Rng2 = Range("A2") ' just for test example
    'Rng1.Value = 0.45 ' just for test example
    'Rng2.Value = 0.45 - 5.55111512312578E-17 ' just for test example
    cell1 = Rng1.Value
    cell2 = Rng2.Value
    If IsNumeric(cell1) Then cell1 = Val(cell1)
    If IsNumeric(cell2) Then cell2 = Val(cell2)
    Debug.Print cell1 = cell2
    Debug.Print cell1 - cell2 ' if both are numbers

Exit Sub
```

also we can use `CDbl(CStr(cell1))` instead of `Val(cell1)`

Comment: I ended up using something similar to this for my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can replicate this issue, which suggests to me that possibly your values are not the values you think they are, but I won't belabor that point.  You could consider casting to string and comparing those values for equivalence:

```
?Cstr(Cell1.Value) = Cstr(Cell2.Value)
```