# Comparing data in two columns with "<>" returns discrepancy while values are actually equal. Formatting?

Tags: excel, vba

This is *not a basic question*.

There are two Excel files generated from two different systems (I can't share them here).

I am comparing two columns which contain decimal values 0.001 up to 0.1.

Data is being fed into arrays and compared entry-to-entry with:

```
 If arrayA(row, col) <> arrayB(row, col) then
    ' we know it's a discrepancy
 End If
```

This however returns that for example 0.035 is not equal to 0.035.

**I tested multiple things:**

1. I created two NEW WORKBOOKS and copied each set of data and pasted as values into the new workbooks. This did not help, again equal values are being recognized as discrepancies.
2. I tried to select the dataset and use the "Clean>All formatting", however this also did not work.
3. I also tried to select both columns and change data type to the same in both columns "Number, General, Text" - same thing was happening.

**Now surprisingly what worked was** :

If I created a 'helper column' and just multiplied values by 100, then copied those, pasted as values to remove formulas. Then I divided those in another helper column back by 100, copied and pasted as values to remove formulas. Then pasted those values back to the original column which was compared --- THIS TIME THE CODE recognized that 0.035 was equal to 0.035, and that 0.3 was equal to 0.3 etc. So this worked.

**I do realize that using** just "<>" directly on two entries compares them using the binary method (the most exact), however I ran out of ideas why this is happening.

One would think that if you copy and paste as values OR clear formatting from both data sets it should be working, but it does not.

I would appreciate any ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like floating-point error. The normal approach is to round to a significant number of digits before doing the comparison. Copy/paste values or clearing the formatting won't affect this, since the underlying *value* remains unchanged. Note that you should use `WorksheetFunction.Round` to round, not `Round`, which uses bankers' rounding.

Comment: Sorry but this is a basic question (in terms of computer science/comparing numbers in VBA) - as @BigBen points out this is likely due the the inexact representation of numbers in binary systems.

Comment: @BigBen could that also happen when both values are exactly 0.035 and 0.035 though? I would understand if there was a difference many places after the decimal point but for two values like 0.01 and 0.01 that do not have any more digits after the "1" it doesn't sound likely?

Comment: They may *look* the same, but they are not. Highly suggest you read this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/

Comment: If it's actually the case that the vallues *look identical* for example 0.01 and 0.01 but they aren't the same, am I able to check it somehow?

Comment: Round them as I suggested.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911129/how-to-check-for-hidden-number-precision-in-an-excel-range

Comment: Oh, also when I compare those two values using =A2=A2 directly in the spreadsheet it returns "TRUE". So I'm guessing this type of comparison is also prone to errors for floating point?